# adding loop in Jframe

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, loops, jframe

hello everyone I need some help here 
I'm trying to make website checker and put the result in a Jframe but it's seems harder than I thought 
because when I make a loop in Jframe with Thread .. the Jframe freezing and nothing work .. is there a simple why to do that ?? 
sorry for my bad English .. I'm your friend from Syria :) 
that's my code

```
private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     

while(true)
{
 try {
     Thread.sleep(500);
 } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
    try{

    InetAddress[] addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName("www.google.com");
  for (InetAddress address : addresses) {
    if (address.isReachable(10000))
    {   
        t1.setText("okay");

       System.out.println("Connected "+ address);
    }
    else
    {
       System.out.println("Failed "+address);
    }
  }
    }catch ( Exception e )
    {}

   }
```

Comment: You should take a look at [Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: *when I make a loop in Jframe with Thread*: you're not starting any thread in the posted code. Read the documentation of SwingWorker

Comment: You should create JFrame and polling loop each in a separate `Thread / Runnable` - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107728/using-a-thread-loop-to-update-a-jframe?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Thread.sleep() in a listener. This code will be executed on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` which is the Thread responsible for handling events and repainting the GUI. By using sleep() you prevent the GUI from responding to event and repainting itself.

Instead you need to create a separate Thread to do your website checking.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. You should probably be using the `Swing Worker`, which is described in the tutorial.